# Firebase Realtime Database to restrict changing specific field

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I got the following problem: multiple users can press a button and I need to catch only the first one pressed when it's allowed. Right now, my security rule looks like this:

```json
"details": {
  "$key": {
    "playerPressed":  {
      ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && (newData.val() == -1 || (data.val() == -1 && newData.val() > -1))" 
    }
  }
}
```

The "playerPressed" field is -1 by default and this is the state when users can press their buttons, so the field value can be changed for higher values of their IDs (range 0-9). If one user clicks a button, say 0, the value changes correctly, user is found and others can be blocked immediately in app. The only change allowed now would be a one made by admin, going back to -1 when the next round starts.

However, if two users click in a similar time (say IDs 0 and 1), the field gets updated twice and then it goes back to the first changed value (from -1 to 0, then 1 and then 0 again), so my listener on this field catches three changes in total, while only one should've taken place. If I put my rule as a ".write" rule then the field gets updated (from -1 to 0 and then to 1), which doesn't make any sense to me. Also, if I add a '".write": false' rule, the field gets updated twice as well!

How can I prevent changing a specific field value in this case?

EDIT: In this question it doesn't matter the rule itself, there is no mistake in the rule. The question is about how Firebase works, actually WHY it works like that, that the ".write" rule allows to write non-permitted values, and the ".validate" rule updates the field twice. The other example would be:

```json
"details": {
  "$key": {
    "playerName":  {
      ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 10" 
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, the database behaviour is identical as above. When I change the field to a value that has more than 10 characters, the field GETS UPDATED to the new value and then UPDATED BACK to the previous value, which crashes my app. If such a rule is under the ".write" rule, the value gets updated as well (once, without going back to the previous value).

Comment: Can you show the **code** for an operation that is allowed, and for one that isn't?

Comment: Dunno what kind of what code do you mean, it is just changing one field. I edited my question to be more readable... The rule says what operation is allowed. From -1 you can go higher, but any positive number cannot be changed into another positive numer. Now it changes the value twice and goes back to the first change.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I change the field to a value that has more than 10 characters, the field GETS UPDATED to the new value and then UPDATED BACK to the previous value

Firebase SDKs optimistically update the local state upon write operations. So when you perform a write operation in a client, this sequence of events happens:

1. The SDK updates the local state and fires local events, so that your application can update its UI right away.
2. The SDK then sends the update off to the server, which processes it.
3. If the server rejects the write operation, it informs the SDK of this. The SDK then fires so-called reconciliatory events to update its state, which also allow your app to update the UI again.

So the update showing the invalid state only happens in the client that initiated the write operation, the server and other clients never see this state.

Your code will have to be able to handle this situation. You will either have to ensure that the client never writes any data that the server may reject, or you will have to ensure your client-side handling is robust enough to handle the temporarily invalid state.

Comment: Wow, that makes sense, thank you... However now I know even less about synchronization between the users, no clue how can I distinguish between the local state change in the "optimistic update' scenario and the real DB change... Thank you anyway.